# How can you launch VSCode with multiple extensionDevelopmentPath sources?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to test local changes of [omnisharp-vscode](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode) in conjunction with my own local extension. I can't for the life of me figure out how to boot the VSCode experimental instance with more than 1 extension.

I've tried:

- Providing multiple `extensionDevelopmentPath` arguments when booting
  vscode
- Running omnisharp-vscode and then opening and running my other extension in the experimental instance.

None of the above have worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would probably be to simply move one (or both) extensions into your `.vscode/extensions` directory. This might require you to remove the marketplace installs of those extensions if present. Even though ["development installations" of extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25159) like this are not officially supported yet, they work just fine regardless.